# Alternative expressions to explain jargon in a sentence?

Tags: word-choice

I have this expression (I know it seems to not make sense):

> Groceries being usually presented without the corresponding "belt".

Now, I want to explain what "belt" is. I'm thinking of these two forms:

> ... without the corresponding "belt", that is, without an adequate price tag that users are able to see.

and

> ... without the corresponding "belt". By "belt" we mean ...

What alternative expressions could I use to disambiguate my use of "belt"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are both pretty good: unfortunately, there aren't a lot of good ways to define industry specific terms in the text, so if you have to use the term, you're going to have to define it.

I like the second one better. Put a period, then define belt (You might say, "Belt is an industry term meaning blah blah blah").

One thing I will say, "being usually presented" should be taken out and shot. Is there a reason you can't just say "are presented" or "are usually presented"?

Comment: You made me go back and edit "being" out of my suggestion. :)

Comment: Yeah, the two suggestions I present seem to be the best ones so far. And "are" does sound better than "being".

Answer (score 2):

I think the third version is fine. It might be improved by delaying the presentation and definition of the jargon word until after the reader has absorbed the main message of the sentence:

> . . . without an adequate price tag, which we call a "belt."

Since you've indicated you need to present "belt" first, how about:

> Groceries should bear a "belt," or adequate price tag, but they are usually presented without one.

Comment: I find it surprising how often we give similar answers. +1

Comment: I need to present "belt" first.

Comment: @MrHen: You noticed it too!

Comment: @John: Why do you need to present it first? If there is something dictating your presentation you should be following those guidelines. It will be hard for us to give advice without knowing what the rules are.

Comment: @John: I just edited to add a suggestion for putting *belt* first.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce "belt" after the description:

> Groceries being usually presented without an adequate price tag (or "belt") that users are able to see.

There are few other quirks in the sentence that I am assuming are there intentionally. Namely, the entire thing is a sentence fragment. Without knowing more about the subject and context I would reword it as such:

> Groceries are typically presented without a corresponding price tag (or "belt").